# How to reach a list after splitting a bigger list [python]

Tags: python, list, split

I've got the following string `itemspecs` which includes 2 questions that are separated by #@# and the question parts (question, options, answer...) are separated by ##. I have to make a quiz out of this string.

```
itemspecs = '''
question 1
Wie was de Nederlandse scheepvaarder die de Spaanse zilvervloot veroverde?
##
Michiel de Ruyter
Piet Heijn
De zilvervloot is nooit door de Nederlanders onderschept
##
1
##
Answer B De Nederlandse vlootvoogd werd hierdoor bekend.
#@#
question 2
In welk land ligt Upernavik?
##
Antartica
Canada
Rusland
Groenland
Amerika
##
3
##
Answer D Het is een dorp in Groenland met 1224 inwoners.
'''

x = itemspecs.split('#@#')
for item in x:
    y = item.split('##')
    print(y)
```

But when I run this and type `print(y[0])` I get the first part of question 2, so that is

`question 2
In welk land ligt Upernavik?`

But how can I reach question 1, that is:

```
question 1
Wie was de Nederlandse scheepvaarder die de Spaanse zilvervloot veroverde?
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error...seems your code is correct.

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus I'm not getting an error, but I don't know how to react the first question

Comment: I guess you put the y[0] outside the loop, move the y[0] into the for loop. your code is 100% right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try appending the values to a list and the access it.

**Ex:**

```
x = itemspecs.split('#@#')
res = []
for item in x:
    res.append(item.split('##'))
print res[0][0]
```

**Output:**

```
question 1
Wie was de Nederlandse scheepvaarder die de Spaanse zilvervloot veroverde?
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: `first_question=itemspecs.split("#@#")[0].split("##")[0]`

`print(first_question)`

`question 1
Wie was de Nederlandse scheepvaarder die de Spaanse zilvervloot veroverde?`

Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

## Translated input (deepl.com)

```
itemspecs = '''
question 1
Who was the Dutch shipowner who conquered the Spanish silver fleet?
##
Michiel de Ruyter
Pete Heijn
The silver fleet was never intercepted by the Dutch.
##
1
##
Answer B The Dutch fleet guardian became known as a result.
#@#
question 2
In which country is Upernavik located?
##
Antartics
Canada
Russia
Greenland
United States
##
3
##
Answer D It is a village in Greenland with 1224 inhabitants.
'''
```

## Tested code (Python 3.6.3)

```
x = itemspecs.split('#@#')
for item in x:
    y = item.split('##')
    q = y[0].split('\n')  # Split lines; on Windows use '\r\n'
    q_ = list(filter(None, q))  # Remove empty lines
    print(q_)
```

## Output

```
['question 1', 'Who was the Dutch shipowner who conquered the Spanish silver fleet?']
['question 2', 'In which country is Upernavik located?']
```